# Norm of an operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $T\neq 0, \neq I$ be a linear operator of a Hilbert space such that $T \circ T = T $. Show that $\|T\|=\|I-T\|$.

Anyone has an idea ? I just proved that $\|I-T\| \leq 1 + \|T\|$ but it is not useful.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's true/ Consider $T = I$. It is true that $T^2 = I^2 = I$, but $1 = ||I|| = ||T|| \ne ||I -T|| = ||0|| = 0$.

Comment: @xyzzyz I edited, $T$ is supposed not to be null or identity.

Comment: How about $T = -I$, then $T^2 = I$ and $\| T\| = 1$ and $\| I- T \| = \| I+I \| = 2\|I\| = 2$

Comment: Alternatively $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, T(x, y) = (y, x)$. We have $T^2 = I$, so $||T|| = 1$, $(T-I)(x, y) = (y - x, x - y)$. Let $v = [-1, 1]$. $||v|| = \sqrt{2}$, $(T-I)(v) = [2, 0]$, so $||T-I|| \geq 2/\sqrt{2} > 1$

Comment: I'm so sorry I mistyped : $T$ is a projector $T \circ T=T$

Comment: Check this https://math.temple.edu/~szyld/papers/NumerAlg06.pdf

Comment: Thank you, perfectly what I wanted !